# Having trouble accessing object in JSON

Tags: android, json

I am trying to access the "display_name" object within the following JSON and I cannot seem to grab it. The example JSON is below.

```
{
  "streams": [
    {
      "broadcaster": "fme",
      "_id": 5019229776,
      "preview": "http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_zisss-320x200.jpg",
      "game": "Diablo III",
      "channel": {
        "mature": null,
        "background": "http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/zisss-channel_background_image-06a9d8c1113e5b45.jpeg",
        "updated_at": "2013-03-04T05:27:27Z",
        "_id": 31795858,
        "status": "Barb sets giveaway and making 500m DH set... Join Zisspire, earn Zeny, collect prizes!",
        "logo": "http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/zisss-profile_image-502d7c865c5e3a54-300x300.jpeg",
        "teams": [ ],
        "url": "http://www.twitch.tv/zisss",
        "display_name": "Zisss",
        "game": "Diablo III",
        "banner": "http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/zisss-channel_header_image-997348d7f0658115-640x125.jpeg",
        "name": "zisss",
        "video_banner": null,
        "_links": {
          "chat": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/chat/zisss",
          "subscriptions": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/zisss/subscriptions",
          "features": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/zisss/features",
          "commercial": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/zisss/commercial",
          "stream_key": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/zisss/stream_key",
          "editors": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/zisss/editors",
          "videos": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/zisss/videos",
          "self": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/zisss",
          "follows": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/zisss/follows"
        },
        "created_at": "2012-07-01T21:09:58Z"
      },
      "name": "live_user_zisss",
      "viewers": 775,
      "_links": {
        "self": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/zisss"
      }
    }
  ],
  "_links": {
    "summary": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/summary",
    "followed": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/followed",
    "next": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?channel=zisss%2Cvoyboy&game=Diablo+III&limit=100&offset=100",
    "featured": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/featured",
    "self": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?channel=zisss%2Cvoyboy&game=Diablo+III&limit=100&offset=0"
  }
```

I start with:

```
JSONArray array = getJSONArray("streams");
JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(4); // channel is entry 4 in array
String name = object.getString("display_name");
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. With a more filled out JSON with multiple "channel" entries, I'm not sure how to handle it. I was thinking something like this?

```
String[] name = new String[array.length()];
JSONArray array = getJSONArray("streams");
for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    if(array[i].equals("channel")
        name[i] = array.getString("display_name");
```

I'm sure that last part is crude, and probably quite off from what it should be, but I'm not sure how to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your JSON you have to do the following

```
JSONArray array = getJSONArray("streams");
JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(0); 
object = object.getJSONOBject("channel")
String name = object.getString("display_name");
```

The first item in you json array holds the channel object which contains the  data you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you. Is the reasoning behind the 0 just to get the root of the array? How would I handle it if there were multiple channel entries?

Comment: the reasoning for the 0 is to get the first item in the JSON array. This is where you specify which JSONObject you want from the array. At the moment, you only have one object in the array basically marked by the brackets(  from [ {....} ]). If you had more object you would access them the same way using their position in the array.

Comment: I'm not sure I understsand. So if I had a second entry, I would use getJSONObject(1) and so on? So if I wanted to run a for loop with it, I could just do getJSONObject(i)?

Comment: Exactly. You would use getJSONObject(i) where i would go up to the length of the array

Answer (score 1):

Channel is not the 4th item in your `JSONArray` but a nested object within the first. You have to be careful to follow the [] and {} brackets when parsing `JSON` because `JSONObjects` can contain multiple nested sub-objects and arrays.

```
JSONObject mainJsonObject = new JSONObject(json_string);
JSONArray array = mainJsonObject.getJSONArray("streams");
JSONObject channelObject = array.getJSONObject(0).getJSONOBject("channel")
String displayName = channelObject.getString("display_name");
```